# AngularJS Html Elments Not Showing Properly After Ajax

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I simply generating a table using ajax/http service. I put button on the last table column. But it shows only plain text.

[image]

MY CODE:

```
<table  border="1" class="ExcelTable2007" style="margin-top:10px;">                 
    <tr>
        <th> COL1 </th>
        <th> COL2 </th>
        <th> COL3 </th>
        <th> COL4 </th>
        <th> COL5 </th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    foreach($orders as $order)
    {
        ?>
        <tr> 
            <td>x</td> 
            <td>x</td> 
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>
              <button class="w3-button w3-green w3-border w3-padding-small" 
                      ng-click="view_order(history.ID)">
                VIEW INFO
              </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>        
</table>
```

Binding:

```
<div class="w3-responsive" >
     <p>SEARCH <input type="text" ng-model="srch"></p> 
     <div ng-bind-html="ora_orders"></div>      
</div>
```

PLS HELP.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding type = button for button element

```
<button type="button" class="w3-button w3-green w3-border w3-padding-small"
        ng-click="view_order(history.ID)">VIEW INFO</button>
```